# Differentiate between updates and inserts in MS Access Form.AfterUpdate

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a bound form in MS Access.  I want to be able to tell:

1. When a new record is inserted
2. When an existing record is updated

I thought the events `Form.AfterUpdate` and `Form.AfterInsert` would be perfect for this, but I just tested `Form.AfterUpdate` and found that it fires after updates *and inserts*.

Is there some way to tell the difference between updates and inserts from within `Form_AfterUpdate()`?  Or is there another approach to detecting these events within Access that I should consider?

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Debug.Print "after insert"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Debug.Print "after update"
End Sub
```

When I insert a new record, this is printed:

```
after update
after insert
```

When I update an existing record, this is printed:

```
after update
```

Comment: Maybe `If Me.NewRecord Then`.

Comment: @June7 I just tried that.  Unfortunately, `Debug.Print "after update " & Me.NewRecord` printed `after update 0` in both cases.

Comment: Try making a form-level boolean variable called `blnNewRecord`. Then set it to the `.NewRecord` value on `Form_Current`. You can then test `blnNewRecord` in `Form_AfterUpdate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really just need to know if this was a new or existing record commitment, use the `BeforeUpdate` event to set a module-level variable that can then be read in the `AfterUpdate` event.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim booNew As Boolean

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    booNew = Me.NewRecord
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Debug.Print IIf(booNew, "New", "Existing")
End Sub
```

Comment: [Making wrong code look wrong](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) explains why `booNew` is a horrible name, and the difference between the useless *Systems Hungarian* (e.g. `booNew`) and *Apps Hungarian*. Hungarian Notation never intended to encode data types in variable names, *as per its inventor*.

Comment: And my research suggested use b as prefix for Boolean and g for global, so maybe gbNew. Whatever. Bad is inconsistency.

Comment: The problem is that Hungarian notation make it ***easier*** to wind up with inconsistent naming, not harder.  I've repeatedly (and on a daily basis on SO) seen the variable prefix not matching the declared type. If you have `strFoo`, and it's not a string, how is that either "consistent" ***or*** helpful?

Comment: Whatever. Just pointing out that an article written by the author of the VBA specifications about the origins of Hungarian Notation discusses how its inventor never intended for prefixes to contain any indicator about that variable's data type - what caused this was a stupid mistake and it blew out of proportions in the 90s and was all over MSDN and in tons of blogs, where your research likely led you. Would be nice if SO answers 30 years later would stop perpetuating this silliness. HN is heavily discouraged in every modern naming standard.

Comment: Downvoted based on opinion? Seen enough opinions against appHungarian as well as for. The answer solved user's issue. They can modify for whatever coding style they prefer.

Comment: @June7 That is a frustrating downvote.  Just wait till they find out your preference for spaces or tabs :P

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that if this matters to you, then you should not be using either `AfterUpdate` or `AfterInsert` but in fact `BeforeUpdate` event. You do not say why you need to know whether a record is an insert or an update, nor what you plan to do in either cases. Even so, I am having hard time of conceiving a good scenario where you need to know that in an `After***` event.

In the `BeforeUpdate`, you still can check the `NewRecord` property and take some actions based on this. More importantly, you get to cancel the attempt to insert/update by setting the `Cancel` parameter to true within the `BeforeUpdate` event.

Also, to present with a different option - if the action you wish to perform is data-centric and would be true regardless of how the data get entered, via this particular form or not, you should consider using data macros instead, which does differentiate between inserts and updates. Note that you still can call VBA code out from data macros in the case the data macro actions are not sufficient for what you need to do.

The `AfterUpdate` and `AfterInsert` events are fine for doing things after the fact and usually won't care about how the record came to be. Examples include stuff like refreshing a related form, changing the focus, enabling/disabling controls, that kind of stuff. Note that the examples I cited were all UI-related. That's what it is for and should be used like so.

Comment: There are uses for AfterUpdate just as there are uses for after triggers in SQL Server.  In this particular case, one reason not to use BeforeUpdate is because it fires even if the update or insert will fail (say due to a primary key violation).  I'm using this for a hackjob where I've been asked to mirror a SQL Server table (manipulated solely via Access) to an IBM database.  I plan to watch for inserts, updates, and deletes and execute ADO queries to keep the two tables synced.  I'd rather use SQL Server triggers if I could, but the two databases are not linked so I think I'm out of luck.

Comment: I wouldn't try to make that comparison. For one thing, `AfterUpdate` of a form is a UI thing whereas a `AFTER` trigger of SQL Server is bound with the data and is independent of how data arrived. Furthermore, the `AFTER` trigger is somehow of a misnomer as you still can rollback it back so it's still "before". Note that Access has supported the equivalent of table triggers via data macros, which provides you with UI-independent means of reacting to the data changes. That might be more appropriate for the purpose of auditing or tracking some changes.

Comment: Interesting, I had never heard of data macros.  However, I have linked tables, so I don't think they are an option for me.

Comment: If linked tables are Access, it still can be used. If linked tables are ODBC, then you'd have to use the backend's triggers in their particular dialect.