# How can I discern whether or not a record is being inserted or updated in Access events?

Tags: ms-access

MS Office 365 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

I have a before change trigger/event in an Access DB.  Since there is no before insert trigger/event specifically, I have to rely on the before change to check the data before the insert.  I need to determine whether or not this record is being inserted or updated in an "if" statement in the trigger/event definition.  And I don't know how to do that.  Any ideas ?

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835441/differentiate-between-updates-and-inserts-in-ms-access-form-afterupdate/54835638#54835638

Comment: Are you talking about VBA on a form, or triggers on a table? Both have a very different approach to this problem